No sound on computer while on a call with Bluetooth headset (Windows 11)
Weeks ago, I used to be able to get on calls with my Bluetooth headset with no problems, except, obviously, hearing everything on low quality audio (which happens with Bluetooth devices when the microphone is in use) However, recently I cant hear ANYTHING as soon as i join a call (discord, teams, etc.) or when my microphone is in use. I can't even hear the other people on the call, but they can hear me clearly through my headset mic. I tried disabling the hands-free mode, but that just deactivates my mic, and that's not what i want. I want to be able to talk and hear with the same device (with the low quality audio, idc). I've tried EVERYTHING, the input/output devices are chosen correctly on all apps and computer, I've even tried reinstalling drivers (bluetooth and sound), also tried reinstalling windows and nothing has worked yet. does anybody have a solution?
I want to be able to hear and talk at the same time with my Bluetooth headset :(
EDIT: okay, so i've investigated a little and came to the conclusion that whenever i join a call, my input chooses the Hands-free channel (HFP) however, my speaker stays in A2DP (stereo, high-quality audio at high latency channel), explaining why my cimputer mutes since it's not possible to use both at the same time (Both have to be in HFP).
The problem is that i can't find this channel or profile in the payback tab, and all that shows is the "headphones" device, which has the stereo type profile (A2DP).
So my question is: How do I install/force the HFP profile for my bluetooth headset?

Welcome to Superuser. Please note that saying you've "tried everything" doesn't tell us much that helps us understand your problem. Instead, please clearly list each thing you have tried, including enough detail that we understand what you have done. Did you do a Clean reinstall of Windows, or a repair? Have you tried a different headset? I've never had an issue with quality on a BT headset decreasing when using the mic. This leads me to believe your headset is bad/faulty.
